# on change of defaultOpenKeys values does not rer-ender antd menu component

Tags: reactjs, antd

**What I want:**

I want to open (expand) the submenu of a specific menu when I change/update the `defaultOpenKeys` value.

**What I've tried:**

```js
const [submenu, setSubmenu] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  setSubmenu(["sub1"]);
}, []);

...

<Menu style={{ width: 256 }} defaultSelectedKeys={["4"]} defaultOpenKeys={submenu} mode="inline">
  <Menu.Item key="1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
  <SubMenu key="sub1" title="Submenu">
    <Menu.Item key="3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
  </SubMenu>
</Menu>;
```

In here, The submenu is an empty array at first, but whenever the page loads, `useEffect` does update the value of `submenu` and set to the `["sub1"]`. What I believe is, whenever the state values do change, the page should re-render, so `<Menu defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']} ...>` should update like this, right?

But in here, if I pass `<Menu defaultOpenKeys=['sub1'] ... >` at first then this works as I expected, but If I pass the `defaultOpenKeys` value from the state, then this does not work as I expected (if the initial value of state is `['sub1']` then it also works fine).

Here is the code sandbox, where I've included both working and not working demo.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-qopqb?file=/src/App.js)

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

**UPDATED:**

After @HDM91 answer,

I've tried with another prop provided by antd, which is `openKeys` and it does open the submenu at first, but was unable to close it, or even it does block other submenus from opening/closing.

```js
<Menu
 style={{ width: 256 }}
 defaultSelectedKeys={["4"]}
 openKeys={submenu} // blocks other submenu by closing and opening
 mode="inline"
>
```

Comment: what about openKeys prop ?

Comment: Hi @HDM91, I've tried it out by making a child component and passing the props as well, seems not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried with openKeys and and handle onOpenChange to set new openkeys into submenu state it's fine:

```
  const [submenu, setSubmenu] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSubmenu(["sub1"]);
  }, []);
  return (
    <Menu
      style={{ width: 256 }}
      defaultSelectedKeys={["4"]}
      defaultOpenKeys={submenu}
      openKeys={submenu}
      onOpenChange={(openKeys) => {
       setSubmenu(openKeys);
      }}
      mode="inline"
    >
      <Menu.Item key="1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
      <SubMenu key="sub1" title="Submenu">
        <Menu.Item key="3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
      </SubMenu>
    </Menu>
  );
```

Comment: I've got your point, thanks it's working now as expected. Actually I just got to know, we don't need to pass `defaultSelectedKeys`, only passing the value for `openKeys` does work.

Comment: it is not working as I expected, it doesn't close and even it blocks to expand other submenus. Do you know, how to get rid of it?

Comment: I think you would handle onopenchange event and then set satet based on openkeys of events, I've just edited my answer to show how do this

Comment: Thanks @HDM91, now it's working as expected now.